# Is there anything awkward in saying " Prince Charles is now a husband"?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, word-order

In my English class today my prof gave us a sentence:

> Prince Charles is now a husband.

He then told us to find out if there is anything wrong with this sentence as our homework.  Undoubtedly, this sentence is grammatically right. The only possible problem is it may not agree with the conventional English use. I think it's maybe because the "now" is a bit out of place, but I'm not sure.  (The only thing I can sense is that if we transform the sentence into " Now Prince Charles is a husband" or " Prince Charles is a husband now"  they'll certainly sound perfect).  I'm not a native speaker.  Can anyone help me about this!  Best regards.

Comment: This sentence sounds perfectly natural to me, and ["*is now*" certainly still sees regular (if slightly declining) use](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is+now&year_start=1800&year_end=2008). In particular, the *1977 - 2008* link shows plenty of modern use.

Comment: Well, he was already a husband quite some time ago now.

Comment: @Josh61 well I know the sentence must be old fashioned now.  But that doesn't matter. We only deal with English usage here ;)

Comment: Why not say he's _now married_ instead? Choosing the description in the OQ is rather unusual, and so must call attention to some feature. But which one?

Comment: @JohnLawler do you mean that "he's married" is more natural than "he's a husband"?

Comment: I agree with @JohnLawler on this one. "is now a husband" implies the fact that he wasn't before. Stating this as "is now married" instead seems indeed more natural, or rather intuitive (at least to me). The given sentence is as you already stated not *wrong*. In other news: "The tickets are now diamonds!"

Comment: @kasoban But what if the sentence is indeed intended to mean " He wasn't a husband before. But now he is. "?

Comment: If it boils down to changing from not-married to married, then there is no difference in implication. If it instead implies a wholly different change which results in him becoming a husband, then that's a different story. As in "Prince Charles is now a husband. He was a wife before."

Comment: It seems to me that "now" is a less problematic modifier than, for example, "currently" or "at this point" or "for the time being" would be. To judge from other comments above, "now" mainly creates a distinction in people's minds between the present and the past, whereas the other options underscore not just the break with the past but the uncertainty of the prince's matrimonial stability going forward.

Comment: 'Prince Charles is now married' would be a more natural way to phrase it. Sorry, I can't really explain why!

Comment: It's less awkward than saying "Prince Charles is now a queen."

Comment: @Hot Depends on who's talking. Though I guess the _now_ bit is even more misleading there than in the original phrase…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pragmatically, 'husband' is normally used as an [inalienable noun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inalienable_possession).  (A table in a paper on ["Alienable vs. inalienable possessive constructions"](http://www.eva.mpg.de/lingua/conference/08_springschool/pdf/course_materials/Haspelmath_Possessives.pdf) by Martin Haspelmath suggests that 'husband' appears as possessed 74% of the time in numbers based on the British National Corpus, more than any other kinship term listed except 'grandmother'.)

Inalienability is not as strongly marked a category in English as it is in other languages, but "is now a husband" on its own feels somewhat bare.  Compare similarly:

> ? Prince Charles is now a brother-in-law.
>      ? Prince Charles is now a boss.
>      ? Prince Charles is now a neighbor.

If this is all we're communicating, we're more likely to indicate the possessor and say *my brother-in-law, the boss of sector 7G, your neighbor, his husband*, or rephrase altogether (*He was promoted, he got married, he had someone move in next door*)

We can make these words alienable if we are talking about the quality of or a change in the relation rather than the fact (*He's a bad boss, you're a good husband, he became a father*), or if the relation is relevant on its own (*I'm a mother now, so I need to...*).

In light of that, "Prince Charles is now a husband" is basically only something you'd say by itself if being a husband *per se* was something he'd been aspiring to.